# Creating a curve path for gameObject which reacts to Triggers

Tags: unity

I am trying to create a path for a gameObject which will bounce off other gameObjects if it hits them. Can I get an idea on how I could possibly get this curve path set up.

Stuck on ideas. I don't want to use ITween and I can't simply define the entire path via ITween either. I need to account for whether it hit another gameObject and cause it to carry on the path or just fall through.

Attached the image below for clarification. I need the circle(purple) gameObject to bounce along the white path provided the rectangle(green) gameObject is in place to cause a Trigger and let the path carry on or the circle gameObject just simply falls through.

There is only 1 green gameObject at any point of time which moves to one of the 3 possible positions. Placed 2 just for clarification.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the only deviation from the path is falling through you could make the object follow a parabolic function, check it at a certain point and if your green thing is there then send the object back along the same parabola. You can use something like [this graph calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) to find the right curve.

```
y = -(a*x)*(x - contact)
```

If you modify 'a' in the equation above you can modify the height of the parabola while still hitting the x axis at 'contact'. a = 2 will be taller while a = 0.5 will be shorter.

Comment: will u be able to show me a simple example.

Comment: `bounce_dist = 100; //distance between each bounce

x_pos += x_speed * elapsed_time; //Update position
x_parab_pos = (x_pos % bounce_dist);
parab_direction = -1; // turns the parabola upsidedown
y_pos += parab_direction * (height_modifier * x_parab_pos) * (x_parab_pos - bounce_dist) + y_fallthough_pos;
if (y_pos < y_fallthough_pos + 1 && !checkForThinger() ){ ... }` That's probably more simple than what you'd want to implement (as speed fixed to x axis might not be the effect you want) but it would be along these lines.